# Request.getParameter is wrongly decoding the string

Tags: java, query-string, urlencode

I have the URL with the following query string

```
equipmentAccessoryRoute=LFVR+BASICACC
```

When I do `request.getParameter("equipmentAccessoryRoute")` it returns 'LFVR BASICACC' in a string variable, replacing plus sign with space.

To resolve this issue I did something like this

```
String accessoryRoute = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("equipmentAccessoryRoute"),"UTF-8");
```

It worked perfectly but now yt is not working for the following query string (which was working before)

```
`equipmentAccessoryRoute=C1000IP5EL@-A`
```

Decoding converts this into 'C1000IP5EL%40-A' and stores into a string.

I am really confused. I tried to learn URL encoding but find it very hard to understand.

Comment: Are you trying to **encode a URL?**

Comment: That is what `URLEncoder.encode()` is supposed to do, see [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding).

Comment: Yes, I agree @Andreas  - I don't see your problem, **Adeel**.

Comment: @Momoro: I just want to keep '+' and '@' sign from query parameter into my java string.

Comment: `LFVR+BASICACC` is the encoded version of `LFVR BASICACC`. `LFVR%2BBASICACC` is the encoded version of `LFVR+BASICACC`. The values in your query string are supposed to be **encoded**.

Comment: @Adeel But they are not valid characters in a query string. See the link I provided.

Comment: You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: @Adeel You have to encode your URL at client side for keeping the `+` and `@` sign in java string.

Comment: This is not an 'issue'. It is correct behaviour. If you want the `+` you have to encode it in the URL argument. And what `request.getParameter()` is doing is *decoding*, not encoding.

Answer (score -2):

URL - Uniform Resource Locator

- URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII
  character-set. Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII
  set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
- URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by
  two hexadecimal digits.
- URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space
  with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But why plus sign is converted to space ?

Comment: + sign will be replaced with %2B from UTF-8 and space will be converted to %20 or + sign but usually spaces converted to %20.

Comment: The question is about URL *arguments*, which are encoded differently.

Comment: @user207421 thats what I explained him , URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.  what's wrong in that?